# Nested loop in python3

Tags: python-3.x

> How does a nested loop work?
>   I tried to make a triangle this is my code:

```
x = 0
string = ""
while x <= 5:
  y = x
  while y > 0:
    string = string + "*"
    y = y - 1
  string = string + "\n"
  x = x + 1

  print(string)
```

> But it came out like this And this is the output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

> How does a nested loop work in python?

Comment: What's the obtained output?

Answer (score 0):

**You must debug your code to understand how the nested loop works**

for your code, the nested loop will work as following,

for each `x` where `x= 5` the while loop of `y` will run for 5 times,

then again,

when `x=4` the while loop of `y` will run for 4 times,

and as per this the while loop of `x` will have 5 iterations and the while loop of `y` will have about 15 iterations equivalent to number of stars in your pyramid or pattern.